# Point size based on scale and point color based on attribute in SLD

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, sld

I want to edit points size based on the scale and also I want to set up colors based on one attribute column (Quantities in ArcMap, 10 classes).

I already wrote SLD rules for colors, but I don't know how to insert maxscale and minscale for the same points.

For example my SLD looks like this:

```
<sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>0,000001 - 0,363959</sld:Name>
          <sld:Title>0,000001 - 0,363959</sld:Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyName>attribute</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>1E-06</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>0.363959</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
            </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#5ABA00</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>4</sld:Size>
              <sld:Rotation>0</sld:Rotation>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
        <sld:Rule>
          <sld:Name>0,363960 - 1,414790</sld:Name>
          <sld:Title>0,363960 - 1,414790</sld:Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyName>attribute</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>0.36396</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>1.41479</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
            </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
              <sld:Mark>
                <sld:WellKnownName>circle</sld:WellKnownName>
                <sld:Fill>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#83CF00</sld:CssParameter>
                  <sld:CssParameter name="fill-opacity">1.0</sld:CssParameter>
                </sld:Fill>
              </sld:Mark>
              <sld:Size>4</sld:Size>
              <sld:Rotation>0</sld:Rotation>
            </sld:Graphic>
          </sld:PointSymbolizer>
        </sld:Rule>
```

Where and how do I insert max scale and min scale rule?

The max zoom out must be Australia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt with SLD you should always read the [spec](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sld) or if you are in a hurry and what you want is pretty simple then check out the [SLD Cookbook](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/).

In this case the cookbook provides the answer at http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-cookbook/points.html#zoom-based-point